# Reading and analyzing data from Excel sheets using pywin32

Tags: python, excel, pywin32

I've seen plenty of examples on how to write to excel, and my program requires reading from existing data. I need to read through a column and pick out numbers from it (the column is empty cells with numbers at arbitrary intervals), and then break out when I reach the end of the data. The code I have now is below, where xlsht is the sheet name, x and y are the cell indices, and address is the list all the numbers are going.

```
while y < xlsht.UsedRange:
    if str(xlsht.Cells(x,y).Value).isdigit:
        address.append(xlsht.Cells(x,y).Value)
        y += 1
        continue
    else:
        y += 1
return address
```

As it stands now, it crashes at line 2. I tried using

```
if xlsht.Cells(x,y).Value not None:
```

but that didn't work. I dont know how else to do this. Also, I wanted to verify that using

```
xlsht.UsedRange
```

is the correct way of detecting the last row of the sheet.

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: @AaronDigulla Its long and i dont know what parts are relevant, [heres a screencap of the consol](http://i.imgur.com/Xzjgb.jpg)

Comment: The important part would be `Exception occurred`; this is the place were sensible programmers put useful error messages that help to figure out what happened ...

Comment: I know that. I already stated I dont know the correct way to determine the values of cells, so coding in error messages is meaningless at this stage.

Comment: I was referring to the fact that Microsoft is only hiring the world's best and smartest and can't even get a simple error message right :-(

Comment: haha righto. 'Uncaught exception' is just the help i was looking for. That way i can put it in a try/catch block and really get frustrated /sarcasm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message doesn't give any useful clues what the problem might be.

Soltuion: Poor man's debugger. Print all and any variables so you can see what is going on:

```
print 'xlsht=',xlsht
print 'x=',x
print 'usedRange=',xlsht.UsedRange
while y < xlsht.UsedRange:
    print 'y=',y
    print 'cell=',xlsht.Cells(x,y)
    print 'value=',xlsht.Cells(x,y).Value
    if str(xlsht.Cells(x,y).Value).isdigit:
        address.append(xlsht.Cells(x,y).Value)
        y += 1
        continue
    else:
        y += 1
return address
```

You get the idea. If you're using Python 3.x, you'll need `print('x=',repr(x))`

Comment: rigtho, this helped me get a few bugs out. Im stuck at how to determine what is in the cell now: `if str(xlsht.Cells(x,y).Value).isdigit:` isn't doing anything good. I just realized that this makes it a string, then checks if that string is a digit. Obviously not gonna work :p

Comment: and as a note the other way i tried doesnt work, `if xlsht.Cells(x,y).Value.isdigit:`

Comment: Try `dir(xlsht.Cells(x,y))` - that should give you a list of methods and properties of whatever `Cells()` returns.

Comment: it lists these: `['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__getnewargs__', '__getslice__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rmul__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'count', 'index'`, any clues you see in there? I was thinking of `contains` or `eq` but im not sure what to compare against

Comment: What do you get for `xlsht.Cells(x,y).__class__`?

Comment: lots of garble... `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#83>", line 1, in <module>
    dir(xlsht.Cells(x,y).__class__)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 466, in __getattr__
    return self._ApplyTypes_(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 459, in _ApplyTypes_
    self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(dispid, 0, wFlags, retType, argTypes, *args),
com_error: (-2146827864, 'OLE error 0x800a01a8', None, None)`

Comment: Thanks for your help with this. After much frustration, I just am going to use a converter and process excel using openpyxl